# Как скопировать проект в Android Studio, чтобы изменения в копии не влияли на оригинал?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пробовал скопировать и переименовать папку проекта, однако столкнулся с проблемой - всё, что я пишу в копии автоматически переносится в оригинал

Пути, ведущие к оригиналу и копии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не очень понятно что именно вы пытаетесь сделать, скопировать проект можно через проводник и все, добавьте немного больше информации

Comment: если вы имеете в виду, что оригинальное приложение заменяется при установке 
скопированного проекта, то надо у копии поменять `applicationId` в `gradle.build`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, нет, до установки на устройство я ещё даже не дошёл. Проблема в том, что когда я набираю код в копии, тот же самый код появляется в оригинале

Comment: Как копировали? Хочу так же попробовать.

Comment: @V.March, копировал папку с проектом, затем переименовывал скопированную папку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

лично я сам использую архивацией через программу:
1) в левом верхнем углу клик по **File** и выбираем "**Export to Zip file**". указываем пути.
2) по указанному пути находим наш архив. разархивируем его. *меняем имя самой **папки***. ложим переименованную папку к другим проектам.
3) выходим в среде в меню проектов -> **Open**. находим нашу новую папку. она будет подсвечена ***НЕ*** значком папки. нажимаем **ОК**. вылазит меню "настроек проекта". ничего не трогам -> **ОК**.

получаем точную копию исходного проекта с другим названием, но одинаковыми `Package`.

Comment: Премного благодарен!)

Answer (score 1):

Заходите на Гит. Там есть вот такая вот кнопочка. Получаете оттуда ссылку.

[image]

Далее в студии File -> New -> Project From Version Control -> Git 
Вставляете туда вашу ссылку и все. У вас склонированный проект который никак не влияет на оригинал.

Comment: А без загрузки на Гит есть возможность это сделать?

Comment: Ну скопируйте просто папку проекта с компьютера в другую с другим названием

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает, всё равно как только я начинаю менять код в копии, он меняется в оригинале

Comment: @ЭрнанКортес, код меняется одновременно в обоих? Или по-любому только в оригинале? Как вы это определили?

Comment: @woesss, пишу код в копии проекта, загружаю оригинал, там этот код тоже есть (если оба проекта открыты одновременно, происходит то же самое)

Comment: @ЭрнанКортес, что-то у меня при всём желании так не получается. Вы уверены, что открыли копию, а не ту же самую папку? Можно попробовать следующее: закрыть другие проекты и выполнить `menu->File->Invalidate Caches / Restart...` Если не поможет, то закрыть проект, удалить его из превью, закрыть студию, в папке копии удалить папки `.gradle` и `.idea` (только с точками в начале) и файл `<ИмяПроекта>.iml`. Запустить студию и импортировать копию проекта заново.

Comment: *А без загрузки на Гит есть возможность это сделать?* Кстати да - импортировать проект можно и из локального  git-репозитория: в качестве ссылки вставляем путь к папке с репозиторием и вперёд. Если в проекте включена интеграция с git и сделан хотя бы один коммит, то репозиторий создаётся (если не настроено иное) в папке проекта. То есть импортировать можно прямо из папки оригинала в новую.

Comment: @woesss, в том, что я открыл не ту же самую папку, я уверен (я сейчас добавил в вопрос пути к оригиналу и копии)

Comment: @woesss, menu->File->Invalidate Caches / Restart..., помогло, спасибо!